# How to know whether to reject a solution?

Tags: roots, quadratics

The question is:

> $x^2 +2(a-1)x + a + 5 = 0$
> For what value of $a$ will the roots of the quadratic equation be equal in magnitude and opposite in sign?

For a general quadratic $ax^2+bx+c = 0$, the sum of roots is equal to $\frac{-b}{a}$. So we just need to set that to zero here.
$$\frac{-2(a-1)}{1}= 0$$

$$\therefore a = 1$$

But if we put $a = 1$ into the original question, our equation becomes $x^2+6=0$ which has no solutions. So the answer for this question is $\phi$. My question is, how am I supposed to know when to test my solutions by plugging them into the original question? Normally when dealing with radicals, inequalities, modulus and when squaring both sides is involved, it's common to have to do this. Here I see none of those things. If anyone can give me a thumb rule for when I should check my solutions and potentially reject some, that would be great!

Comment: You have to remember that you (implicitly) started your solution by saying "assume $a$ is such that the equation ... has two real solutions adding up to $0$". From this you deduced that $a$ must be $1$. You still don't know if $a=1$ is a solution. You only know that if there is any solution, then it must be $a=1$.

Comment: I get that, but such implicit assumptions are very common, especially in problems of (nature of) roots of quadratics. What if I get ranges of values for questions based on inequalities? Is it a good habit to check all solutions (or ranges of solutions for inequalities)?

Comment: In full generality, yes. Alternatively, you could write a statement which is *equivalent* to the fact that your equation has two real solutions that add up to $0$. That statement would be "$a-1=0$ and $\Delta\geq 0$" and then solving this system of equations/inequalities would give you the exact answer. Perhaps in some cases it may be easier to solve such a full system, rather than solve part of it and verify the other part.

Comment: By "the sum of roots",  a must be 1. Besides checking that we must add another check which is "the product of roots". After ANDing the two requirements, we find that there is no such an "a".

Comment: I don't know that I'd reject $ \ a \ = \ 1 \ $ as the solution:  the question as written _does not state_ that the roots must be real and $ \ x \ = \ \pm i·\sqrt6 \ $ certainly satisfy the requirement that the roots be opposite in sign and equal in magnitude (modulus).  Implicit assumptions can become pitfalls on exams (or even homework problems) and in competition problems.  (You ask for a "rule of thumb":  upon finding solutions, _always_ go back to the problem statement and check _exactly_ what is written before accepting or rejecting your results.)

Comment: Concerning my last point: I worked with good students who would get "killed" on multiple-choice problems because the result they'd worked out was in the wrong units (for which a choice was provided, of course...) or had a result that didn't answer the question _exactly_ as stated (and either a matching choice was available, or they couldn't find their result among the choices and so just "guessed" for their choice).